# Updatetext funciton in SQL 2005 wth asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, sql-server

I have the table, called Contract in my DB.
There is column Comment(datatype text).

I'm trying to add some comments a lot of times to this column from my asp.net application.

Just like concatenate text in this cell with new text from textbox.

Maybe there is an easiest way to do it, but I didn't find anything, except updatetext.

Updatetext looks like

`UPDATETEXT { table_name.dest_column_name dest_text_ptr } 
     { NULL | insert_offset } 
     { NULL | delete_length } 
     [ WITH LOG ] 
     [ inserted_data 
     | { table_name.src_column_name src_text_ptr } ]`

But I don't understand, what is dest_text_ptr.
That is a pointer, but how to use it in my example?

Comment: As I understand, I must use smth like: `     myCommand.CommandText = " DECLARE @ptrval VARBINARY(16) SELECT @ptrval = TEXTPTR(Comment)   FROM Contract   WHERE id ='" + GridView1.SelectedRow.Cells[2].Text + "'  UPDATETEXT Contract.Comment @ptrval NULL NULL '" + comment + "'";
               `